# Uploads via InitiateFileTransferToGuest is extreamly slow

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

The [InitiateFileTransferToGuest](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/98d63b35-d822-47fe-a87a-ddefd469df06/2e3c7b58-f2bd-486e-8bb1-a75eb0640bee/doc/vim.vm.guest.FileManager.html) let's me upload a file to a VM via the ESXi host it's running on.
When I perform the HTTP upload, I'm only getting about 8 Mb/s.

When I use `dd` on the source machine and target VM, I get about 730 MB/s reads & writes.
When I use `iperf` between the source machine and target VM, I get 8 Gb/s throughput.

I get the same HTTP upload speed if I use `curl` or Python's [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module.

All three machines (source, target VM, and ESXi host) are on the same 10 GbE subnet.

Is there some HTTP buffer setting in ESXi that needs adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the file is traversing the host and going into the VM with no reliance on the VM's networking configuration. It's using the VM's instance of VMware Tools.

This certainly won't be the most performant option, as you've found already, but it is extremely handy when there are network limitations or the VM is otherwise inaccessible externally, but it is powered on with VMware Tools running.